# Visual Studios 2010 low on memory error / Chrome Crashes after updating Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, windows-8.1

Two days ago Microsoft automatically forced an update for my version of Windows 8.1. Now Visual Studios 2010 gives me a "low on memory" error twice per day. When the error occurs it forces me to restart Visual Studios.  It was working fine before the update.

[image]

Sometimes (but not always) Chrome will crash simultaneously with this message.

[image]

Update 10/31/2014: Today, I was given an option to debug Chrome when it crashed, and I got this message. The exception: 0xC000041D is documented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2856748/en-us)

[image: chrome exception]

Update 11/3/2014: The Low memory problem persists even after installing the recommended updates including an update for .NET

Update 11/5/2014: Re-sizing Chrome browser window triggers errors.  It is not guaranteed that Chrome and Visual Studios will fail simultaneously. However, after receiving the error message either Chrome or VS2010 will fail immediately.  If one program is still active, then it is guaranteed that the active program will fail some number of minutes later.

How do I fix this?

Comment: please post exact errror message

Comment: @MitchWheat exact message added. Also, saw some cases yesterday where Chrome crashed simultaneously.

Comment: I've installed the updates mentioned the Microsoft link for the exception above, and will report back if the crashing stops.